# infinite execution while taking input through console

Tags: java, input

I am not a total newbie but I got caught in a strange problem while taking input through console in java! Here is my code:

```
package com.test;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenSum {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int a1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    // tried through scanner class even
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a3 = scan.nextInt();

    String input = br.readLine();
    int a2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int a = in.readInt();

    scan.close();
}
}
```

I have tried doing it by all the four ways separately but the execution of the code simply doesn't end it keeps going on and on. Did I break something? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used `br.readLine()` 4 times and `scan.nextInt();` 1 time your code will ask to input value 5 times, instead create object of `Scanner` and read `int` or `String` according to your requirement.

Comment: Hello Vishrant as I have already mentioned in my post that I have written separate programs to test all the approaches. Just for showing what approaches I have tried I have written it all at one place in the code shown in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>   int num = input.nextInt();

Comment: I have tried even this mike!... Can you make out what the problem is? I think my code is correct!.. ;-(

Comment: If you only have those two lines and still doesn't work, the problem is not the code. Actually add input.close(); for future use.